# Unable to connect to "localhost/Moodle"

Tags: moodle

I am new (novice) to programming and i appreciate your help. I installed moodle/wamp and started creating a site with moodle. It worked fine for several days. Now when i try to go to "localhost/moodle" i get the following error message: 
" Error: database driver problem detected  The site administrator should verify server configuration  PHP has not been properly configured with the MySQLi extension for it to communicate with MySQL. Please check your php.ini file or recompile PHP. " .

Can anyone help me how to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would have commented, but didn't have enough reputation.

Take a look here https://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=164020 in the Moodle forum. There are several people having the same problem.

- Do you have PHP on its latest version?
- Whats is your "**dbtype**" in the config.php file? I think it should be

  ```
  $CFG->dbtype = 'mysqli';
  ```